# Mysql Fulltext Search on numeric IP

Tags: mysql, ip, full-text-search

I stored the IP as INT(10) in a mysql table. I display the IP as a address and the user should be able to search for a address rather than a numeric value. I can't see a way to tell MySQL that it has to perform an INET_NTOA for the fulltext search. Is there a way I can easily do that within a query or should I just store the IP as char(), i don't like it since it's about 3 times larger than the numeric value.

Comment: IP addresses _are_ numeric values, not text.

Comment: yees, by address i mean the textual representation.

Comment: Convert the user's input into the numeric representation, and search for that.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this -

```
SELECT INET_NTOA(stored_address) AS match FROM my_table
WHERE LOCATE(query, match) != 0
```

I wouldn't necessarily recommend it for a large table, though - it'll end up having to convert every single stored IP address in order to get you your results.

Comment: Do you think it is ok to use it for a table with let's say 500-1000 rows?